# how to create the url in lightning for vf page?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, url, url-encode

I have a vf page on that page i have a custom setting record page link that is working fine in salesforce classic but not in lightning..in Lightning i got this url when i tried that find with setup then this encoded url i got...

```
https://myinstancename/one/one.app?source=aloha#/setup/page?nodeId=CustomSettings&address=/setup/ui/viewCustomSettingsData.apexp?appLayout=setup%26setupid%3DCustomSettings%26sfdcIFrameHost%3Dweb%26isdtp%3Dp1%26sfdcIFrameOrigin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmyinstancename%26tour%3D%26id%3Da0558000005rNUQ
```

i tried to decode it but after applayout i am not able to decode that..and this url is hardcoded..how i create this url in vf page for lightning..please help me.

Comment: Can you Add your custom setting URL which you are referring in VF page? there are several way to navigate in lightning.

Comment: in vf page <a href="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ record.Id + '/view'}" target="_blank"> 

i don't know how i create this(url that i post in question) in vf page

Comment: why are you using one/one.app for navigation in classic

Comment: Which URL you are using for classic? can i see the URL for classic ?

Comment: @ManjotSingh no that is i using for lightning.

Comment: @SagarThoriya for classic i use like this --
<apex:outputLink value="/{recored.id}" > </apex:outputlink>

and this is working fine in classic.

Answer (score 3):

To navigate in lightning experience using URL you can use below syntax,

```
/one/one.app#/alohaRedirect/recordId
```

OR

```
/one/one.app#/alohaRedirect/Vfpage
```

OR ( For custom Setting record detail page)

```
/one/one.app#/setup/page?nodeId=CustomSettings&address=/{!customSettingRecordId}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<script> 
function redirectTo(url){
            if(typeof sforce !='undefined' && sforce.one) {
                    sforce.one.navigateToURL('/one/one.app#/setup/page?nodeId=CustomSettings&address=/'+url);
                }
                else {
                    window.location.href = '/'+url;
                }
        }    
</script> 

<a href="#" onclick="redirectTo({recored.id})">
```

Above will work in both lightning and classic.